# Java: How to make this Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, outputstream

I need the following class to be Serializable.

```
package helpers;

public class XY implements Comparable<XY>
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public XY (int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int compareTo( XY other ) 
    {
        String compare1 = this.x + "-" + this.y;
        String compare2 = other.x + "-" + other.y;

        return compare1.compareTo( compare2 );
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.x + "-" + this.y;
    }

}
```

As of now, I can't send it as an object with outputstream..I´ve tried to implement Serializable, but that didn't work.

Comment: "I´ve tried just to implement Serializable but it doesnt do the trick!" What exactly did you try..? and where exactly were you stuck ?

Comment: This should be as easy as it gets...post your serialization code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing `Serializable` *will* do the trick, but you must write the object with an [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), not just an OutputStream.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to inherit from `java.io.Serializable`:

`public class XY implements Comparable<XY>, java.io.Serializable`

Check more about serialization [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [SerializationUtils API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) provided by Apache Commons Lang.

This is much safer and more maintenance friendly. :)